# ROS Debian in the BBB

Tags: ros, beagleboneblack, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Last week i compiled i set of instructions following http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Debian at http://erlerobotics.gitbooks.io/erlerobot/en/ros/tutorials/rosinstall.html. Leaving aside the Lips dependencies, everything worked fine and i could run roscore.

When I tried today to reproduce it in another board i got stucked at the very beginning:

```
root@beaglebone:~# sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-rosdep : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 python-rosinstall-generator : Depends: python-catkin-pkg (>= 0.1.28) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: python-rosdistro (>= 0.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Trying to install python-catkin-pkg:

```
root@beaglebone:~# apt-get install python-catkin-pkg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But my python installation is:

```
root@beaglebone:~# python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

This is definitely odd. Has something changed in the servers?

NOTE: I also tried to manually install it:

```
root@beaglebone:~# sudo apt-get download python-catkin-pkg
Get:1 Downloading python-catkin-pkg 0.2.3-1 [30.7 kB]
Fetched 30.7 kB in 1s (30.1 kB/s)                    
root@beaglebone:~# dpkg -i python-catkin-pkg_0.2.3-1_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package python-catkin-pkg.
(Reading database ... 67685 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-catkin-pkg (from python-catkin-pkg_0.2.3-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-catkin-pkg:
 python-catkin-pkg depends on python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2).
 python-catkin-pkg depends on python-docutils; however:
  Package python-docutils is not installed.

dpkg: error processing python-catkin-pkg (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-catkin-pkg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186643/ros-debian-in-the-bbb/) by [v.mayoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/4008/v.mayoral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v.mayoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/4008/v.mayoral/) on 2014-07-15**:
In case anyone feels curious, i put the process in a gist (https://gist.github.com/vmayoral/8dea86c42bdd890b3930)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All right, it seems that `apt-get` shouldn't be used in Debian for fetching these packages.

They can be installed through `pip` using:

```
sudo pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [v.mayoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/4008/v.mayoral/) with karma: 88 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-11-13**:
Until arm builds are fully supported the debs may be out of date if you're using an older repo. Note that many times for pure python packages like this the packages can be installed on different targets from where they were compiled.